# bootstrap 3 button group highlighting nth child

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm trying to highlight the first radio button in a bootstrap 3 button group to display a different background colour to the others with CSS.  I can do this with Jquery from the event but it would be nice to get this working. So I tried this on bootply but no luck...

```
.btn-group input[type="radio"]:first-child:checked + label { 
    background-color:#CAFF70 !important;
}
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <input type="radio" id="ok_1" name="options_1" value="ok"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <input type="radio" id="na_1" name="options_1" value="na"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <input type="radio" id="no_1" name="options_1" value="repair"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
  </label>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code input is a child of label which is wrong. Input and label have to be on the same level.

```
<div class="btn-group">

  <input type="radio" id="ok_1" name="options_1" value="ok">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" id="ok_2" name="options_1" value="ok">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></label> 

  <input type="radio" id="ok_3" name="options_1" value="ok">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></label>

</div>
```

[Check here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BowXRK)

Also, if you want to style radio buttons (like buttons you showed) you can read this [tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953).

Comment: Agreed the level is the issue, but "out of the box" bootstrap 3 radio button group structure is correct.  So my question was ... can a CSS selector be built to target a particular radio button exactly how it is... there is the > selector but I can't seem to get it right.  thanks anyway

Comment: No, you can't target it with your HTML code. There is no "radio button structure" in Bootstrap 3.